# There an indirect causal effect of fluid intelligence on crystallize intelligence that is mediated by the manner in which people perceive the world

Tags: intelligence

Evidently, the ability to abstract (fluid intelligence) has a causal effect on crystallize intelligence, that is, the greater the ability to abstract, the greater the acquired knowledge over time. However, knowledge is rather complex. It is defined as a familiarity or awareness, of someone or something, such as facts (**descriptive** knowledge), skills (**procedural** knowledge), or objects (**acquaintance** knowledge) contributing to ones understanding. It is not obvious that people of high fluid intellect tend to acquire all different types of knowledge, typically one develops a specific form of knowledge optimised for their objectives. In other words, the knowledge deemed as most meaningful with respect to their objectives will be the one the person develops most forcefully, and their fluid intelligence determines the extent to which they develop this, e.g., those who perceive the world in terms of objective facts will likely develop their descriptive knowledge and those who perceive the world as a place to exhibit skill will likely develop their procedural knowledge. Hence, there is an indirect causal effect of fluid intelligence on crystallize intelligence that is mediated by the manner in which people perceive the world, phenomenologically.

Comment: Welcome to psych.SE.  There are a lot of unsubstantiated claims made here, some of which I do not believe to be correct.  For example: "the ability to abstract has a causal effect on crystallize intelligence" and "typically one develops a specific form of knowledge optimised for their objectives" and "those who perceive the world in terms of objective facts will likely develop their descriptive knowledge and those who perceive the world as a place to exhibit skill will likely develop their procedural knowledge."  Please provide appropriate references to back them up.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree that individuals of different personalities will develop different skill-sets and aptitudes, I may disagree on the cause proposed in the question. The types of knowledge mentioned can all fit into [schemas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_(psychology)), which are developed by all intellectually healthy persons. From Wikipedia:

> In [psychology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychology) and [cognitive science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_science), a **schema** (plural *schemata* or *schemas*) describes a pattern of thought or behavior that organizes categories of information and the relationships among them.[[1](https://doi.org/10.1146%2Fannurev.soc.23.1.263)][[2](https://doi.org/10.1177%2F00031224211024525)] It can also be described as a mental structure of preconceived ideas, a framework representing some aspect of the world, or a system of organizing and perceiving new information.[[3](https://web.archive.org/web/20131213104606/http://www.psyctherapy.com/Enrolled/glossaryBody1.htm)] [...] Examples of schemata include [academic rubrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubric_(academic)), [social schemas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_cognition#Social_schemas), [stereotypes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereotype), [social roles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_role), [scripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Behavioral_script), [worldviews](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worldview), and [archetypes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archetype).

The associations listed in the question seem essentially as *object-feature* (part of a schema), *state-motion* (script; a type of schema), and *object-identity* (a one-off schema), which any competent person should possess in abundance. Which schemas are most accumulated and reinforced is a matter of experience; which experiences are partaken is a matter of priority; but all mentally healthy humans possess various manners of perception and attention.

Priorities change as *internal state* (e.g. hunger) and *external state* (e.g. threat) change. Handling various combinations of internal and external state is critical for survival. No doubt, the states and combinations (composite states) most experienced are likely to be the most developed in terms of having accurate schemas for their thoughts and actions.

General intelligence is about pattern matching (seeing similarities) and pattern distinction (seeing differences) -- that is, finding and refining schemas. Naturally, the essence of pattern is abstraction. A person of higher intelligence will tend to accumulate schemas faster; but which schemas are found first is heavily influenced by experiences (e.g. education) and priorities (e.g. survival).

Most people have the same basic set of priorities by birth; but internal differences, such as from genes and hormones, influence these priorities and hence the personality. External experience, especially in early childhood, further shapes this personality.